# SQLITE query for words in a list - For loop stops after first word

Tags: python, sqlite, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
con =sqlite3.connect('library.db')
cur = con.cursor()
data=cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM Database''')

for word in word_list:
iteration_counter = 0
    for column in data.description:
        query = f'''SELECT {column[0]} FROM Database WHERE LOWER({column[0]}) = ?'''
        cur.execute(query,(word,))
        output = cur.fetchone()
        iteration_counter += 1
        print(iteration_counter)
```

word_list is a list variable that lowercase words from an input text. I want the function to query each word in the list to find out which column the word is placed under in the database. In order to verify that the for loop works, I make the function print the variable iteration_counter which is incremented for every column that is queried. For the first word in the list, this demonstrably works. For every other word however - the loop stops at 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Program changes the "value" of the cursor (`data`) while it is iterating over the cursor (`for column in data.description:`).

Perhaps use the connection's execute method for the `data` SELECT
eg `data=con.execute('''SELECT * FROM Database''')`

Or instantiate a second cursor for the `query` SELECT by adding line `cur2 = con.cursor` after the connect then using `cur2` inside the inner `for` instead of `cur`.

Comment: I'm struggling a bit with implementing this advice in my code - could you give me an example of how this could be done?

Comment: Clarificateion (hopefully! :) added to answer.

Comment: Ah now I got it - the first cursor is "spent" for the query that creates the data variable. 

This works, thanks a bunch!